# Dynamic theme in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, themes

i want to develop our site in such a way user can choose theme. when user will choose theme then i want show the images of our site' home page with various look and user will just choose the images and theme of our site will be change. i know how to change theme from the code behind.

my question is that how could i display the various images of my site's home page with different look which user choose. please tell me the way out. if possible give me a small code to generate the images of my site's home page with different theme attach which user will choose. if anyone know any sample of such things according to my requirement then please give me the url from where i can download the sample.

thanks

Comment: You say you want to theme an image - do you mean putting a frame around the image or do you want to associate certain images with a selected theme ?

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what you're trying to say, and I would go about it like this:

1. Apply a theme to your site, then run it
2. Take a screenshot of your homepage
3. Open Paint and paste the screenshot onto the canvas
4. Save the image as "MySite_Theme1" or something like that

Once you have followed these steps for each of your themes, do the following to apply each preview to a button

5. Add the screenshots to your site's Images folder.
6. Go back into your site and create an `<asp:ImageButton>` for each theme. Apply ID, ImageURL, ImageAlign, runat, Height, and Width. The control should resize the image based on the button's height & width.
7. Go to [changing themes with buttons, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882703/changing-themes-with-buttons-how) for coding the code behind.

I hope this helps you out

EDIT: I would also look for the book Beginning ASP.NET in C# & VB. Wrox is the publisher. I have found that and a lot more at www.wowebook.com :)

Comment: Sounds like this solution will have problems on computers running different resolutions than yours?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ASP.NET Themes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx) which could be [changed dynamically](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/HTML/ThemeChanging.aspx) at runtime.