# changing themes with buttons, how?

Tags: asp.net, themes

I have 2 themes that i want to use on site, and they are settled in Themes Folder-> theme1 and theme2 , in theme1 and theme2 i have one .css file.
So how will I connect these .css files to two buttons and when i click on button1 i want to theme1.css activates and for theme2. 
If you need more informations about problem ask.
thanks

Comment: I have one doubt...are you using Profile?

Comment: I dont know what "Profile" is , but im sure im not using it .

Comment: @Iari:I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

In the Page_PreInit or before insert the code

```
{
  this.Theme = "myTheme"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample application in asp.net check out this,and let me know if there is some doubt.

**Updated**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ProfilePage.aspx.cs" Inherits="ProfilePage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="test" Text="Stackoverflow" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Theme1" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Theme2" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>




using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class ProfilePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (Request.QueryString["theme"])
        {
            case "Blue":
                Page.Theme = "Blue";
                break;
            case "Red":
                Page.Theme = "Red";
                break;
        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("ProfilePage.aspx?theme=Red");
    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("ProfilePage.aspx?theme=Blue");
    }
}
```

Comment: But i dont have any .aspx for themes , inside App_Themes i have theme1 and theme2 and inside them one .css i that is problem

Comment: You want to do this on page where two buttons are placed

Comment: yes, but my routes to the .css files are different, so i dont have any aspx files with my themes .

Comment: it still doesnt get in to my head how to do it in mine example :(

Comment: do you have some mail so i can contact you ?

Comment: send me your simplified version of code to my email address santi.noida@gmail.com